# Comparing part of a file name to a string in Java

Tags: java

As the title suggest, I'm looking for a way to search for a file name that ends a certain way on my computer. I then want to be able to execute different parts of the program based on whether the file exists or not. I've modified a bit of code that I found online, but I'm having a hard time building out the next step.

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop";
    String files;
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (File checkedFile : listOfFiles){
        if (checkedFile.isFile()){
                files = checkedFile.getName();
                System.out.println(files);
                if (files.endsWith(".VBS")){
                    System.out.println("found =================");
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code will print out every file name on the desktop, and if a file ends with `.VBS` it will print `found ============` to the console. What I am looking for would is a way to check all the files on the desktop based on what it ends with, and compare it to a string. If the ending of the file meets the value of the string, then I proceed with another portion of the code, if it does not, then I proceed with another portion of the code. Something like the pseudo code below is what I'm looking for:

```
 String value = "test.VBS"
 for (File checkedFile : listOfFiles){
            if (checkedFile.isFile()){
                    files = checkedFile.getName();
           }
      }

  if(files.equals(value)){
        //Do this
     } else {
      // Do this
 }
```

Obviously the code above doesn't work, but the idea that the program would loop through the desktop to see if the file name exists, and if it does, check to see if it equals the string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put the `if` judgment within a for loop

```
String value = "test.VBS";
for (File checkedFile : listOfFiles){
    if (checkedFile.isFile()){
        files = checkedFile.getName();

        if(files.equals(value)){
            //Do this
        } else {
            // Do this
        }
    }
}
```